# Java Swing Ghost Component - JSplitPane inside horizontal box inside JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Creating a very basic GUI for a tool I'm making and I ran across an unusual problem. The basic idea is to create a JList and JTable and place them inside a JSplitPane. That split pane will take up most of the space in the JFrame, but there will also be a few buttons placed under the split pane but still within the same JFrame. To accomplish the design I want, I'm using a horizontal Box for the buttons, and a vertical Box for the split pane and the horizontal button Box. I had the split pane designed and working as desired, so I started making the adjustments to add the buttons to the JFrame as well. When I was done making the modifications, the buttons were in the right spot, under the split pane, but there was a ghost component to the left of the split pane. I'm sure its something simple and stupid, but I just can't find where I'm going wrong. Here's some pictures of how it looks.

This is how the split pane looks on its own.
[Split Pane only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uHTU.png)

This is how it looks with the Boxes and Buttons added.
[Boxes and Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMIG4.png)

I'm trying to get rid of the blank space to the left of the split pane.

This is the relevant code:

list is a JList, table and viewTable are JTables

```
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    list.addListSelectionListener(this);
    listScroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    viewTable = table;
    columnModel = viewTable.getColumnModel();
    for(int i = 0;i<columnModel.getColumnCount();i++)
        columnModel.getColumn(i).setMinWidth(150);
    viewTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    dataScroll = new JScrollPane(viewTable,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    dataScroll.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(150);

    splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,listScroll,dataScroll);

    JFrame viewFrame = new JFrame("View/Delete");
    viewFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton deleteButton, revertButton, viewCancelButton;
    Box viewBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    Box ButtonBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    viewCancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    viewCancelButton.addActionListener(this);
    revertButton = new JButton("Revert Changes");
    revertButton.addActionListener(this);
    deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
    deleteButton.addActionListener(this);
    ButtonBox.add(viewCancelButton);
    ButtonBox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30,0)));
    ButtonBox.add(revertButton);
    ButtonBox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30,0)));
    ButtonBox.add(deleteButton);
    viewBox.removeAll();
    viewBox.add(splitPane);
    viewBox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    viewBox.add(ButtonBox);
    viewBox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    viewBox.setVisible(true);
    viewFrame.add(viewBox);
    viewFrame.pack();
    viewFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Thanks in advance for the help! Let me know if you need any more information. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Wrap the JSplitPane in a `JPanel` containing a `BorderLayout` before adding to the vertical box.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `JSplitPane` in a `JPanel` containing a `BorderLayout` before adding to the vertical box. How the result differs has to do with how each layout manager (BoxLayout vs BorderLayout) manages the size of the child components.